# How to create an autoencoder model where the input shape = output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on an autoencoder model. My dataset contains images of shape (256,256,4). I changed them to grayescale before inputting them into the model while training.
My label dataset has images of shape (256,256,1).
I wrote the code:

```
input_img = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# At this point the representation is (7, 7, 32)

x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

The model.summary() is:

```
Model: "functional_10"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_12 (InputLayer)        [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_44 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_45 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_25 (MaxPooling (None, 7, 7, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_46 (Conv2D)           (None, 7, 7, 32)          9248      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_14 (UpSampling (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_47 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_15 (UpSampling (None, 28, 28, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_48 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 1)         289       
=================================================================
Total params: 28,353
Trainable params: 28,353
Non-trainable params: 0
```

As you can see, the input shape is (28,28,1) and the output shape will be that too. That is why I also resized the images.

However, I am looking for a model that gets inputs of shape (256,256,1) and gives outputs of the same shape so that the model is compatible with my datasets. Also, I need higher quality output.

Changing the input shape of this code from (28,28,1) to (256,256,1) does not give the output shape as (256,256,1), rather it is (252,252,1). I am having an intuition why it is, but if someone can explain...

Can someone help me with the code I am looking for? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you code the encoder first and then using `model.summary()`, note down the output shapes of the `MaxPooling2D` layers. Accordingly, add the required number of `UpSampling2D` layers in the decoder. As a side note, I would discourage the use of `MaxPooling2D` and `UpSampling2D` layers. Instead, use `Conv2D` layers with larger stride size. Max pooling layers do not preserve spatial information ( as reduction of input resolution occurs ).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal, thanks! Btw, how can I upsample with stride?

Comment: Use`Conv2DTranpose` layer. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose).